# SMS from Server to be sent to a particular port number in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, sms, sms-gateway

In Blackberry SMSDemo Sample application uses a particular port number through which the message will not be displayed in inbox.

That application works properly if message is sent from a device to device.

I was wondering, if there is a way to send message from server to that particular port number so that the message which is sent from the server will not be displyed in the inbox.

We have tried many method but have been unsuccesfull upto now.

Hoping to hear from you soon

Thanks In Advance 
Krishnan.

Comment: Please tell us *which* methods you've tried, so we can narrow down our suggestions.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to send to a specific port on a handset from a server via UDH.

According [3GPP TS 23.040](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/23040.htm) section 9.2.3.24 (I used version 6.8.1), you can set *Information Element Identifier* octet to any one of the following values and achieve port addressing:

- 0x04 (Application port addressing scheme, 8 bit address)
- 0x05 (Application port addressing scheme, 16 bit address)

16 bit port addressing is commonly used.

#### Dependency

There are two dependency for UDH to work:

- Carrier
- Handset

Officially, UDH is supported only in GSM carriers. A GSM carrier may decide to block messages with UDH or remove the UDH part of messages. Non-GSM carriers are not required to support UDH, but they may.

The handset also should have capability to parse UDH messages.